# Discrepancies between automatic ad revenue event ad_impression and custom ad revenue event paid_ad_impression

Tags: android, firebase, sdk, admob, ads

I have an Android mobile app that implements AdMob ads: Banner, Interstitial, Rewarded and App Open Ads.
I'm using AdMob SDK **OnPaidEventListener** to report user impression level data to firebase with a custom event "paid_ad_impression".
For some reason revenue reported is 15-20% higher then the actual firebase automated ad revenue event "ad_impression".
Is anyone experienced this issue? I talked with my account manager in Google but he couldn't, using the technical support team, figure out the cause of the issue.

Comment: We have exactly the same problem. One of our games has less than 5% difference while the other has 15 to 20%. The difference between the games is that the one with less difference has only rewarded video while the other has rewarded video, interstitial, rewarded interstitial and app open ads. Might that be a reason?

Comment: We have the same problem. Do you find the reason?